# NetBeans 7.3.1 FTP Upload files on save

Tags: netbeans, ftp, save

First programming project in NetBeans and maybe I'm doing the basics wrong. But.... I've created a PHP project and configured a remote connection. The files I code are stored local on my harddisk. When I save a file, then right click and choose upload, the file is upload to my ftp server without any issues, every time.

But when I enable "Upload files: On Save", I see that the file is uploaded and renamed and sometimes it works, but more often I get a "421 Timeout" error. When immediately selecting upload, the file does upload fine.

Files are simple php/html files, so just 1-2k in size.

Any tips on how to fix this? Because Upload on Save would be me preferred method to work.

Gabrie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking "Upload files directly", then no temp. file is beeing used